# After renaming my table in Django, items from the old table were not moved or deleted

Tags: python, django, django-models

My old table called **Quiz** was renamed to **CarQuizz**, the problem is that all items in the table with the old name were neither moved to the new name nor were they deleted.

Here is the following log from my application:

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3fvq.png)

**Models.py**

```py
from django.db import models

class CarQuizz(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url_image = models.URLField(default=None)
    name_quiz = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='Cars')

    def __str__(self):

        return f'{self.name} foi adicionado ao quizz'
```

**Urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('quiz/solo', views.Quiz, name='quiz'),

]
```

I already restarted the Django server, I also deleted the record of the migrations made and did the migrations again, but nothing resolved it. Except when I rename it to Quiz, the program works normally.

Comment: Did you make and run migrations after renaming? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/migrations/

Comment: yeah, I deleted the migrations and did it again

Comment: @danielcerk: you should (almost) never remove migrations. Unless the migration itself errors, and is not applied.

Comment: Can you share the migration file after renaming the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution might be to retain the old table, and just route the `app_name_quiz` to the `CarQuiz` with:

```
from django.db import models


class CarQuiz(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url_image = models.URLField(default=None)
    name_quiz = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Cars')

    def __str__(self):

        return f'{self.name} foi adicionado ao quizz'

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'app_name_quiz'
```

This will not require any migrations: you simply use the old table.